# What is a "small" isotopy?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition

I recently came across the term "$C^\infty$-small isotopy" of some surfaces in a manifold. I sort of understand what an isotopy is intuitively (I read that it's like a homotopy, but only with bending), and I think I get what a $C^\infty$-small isotopy should mean (a smooth isotopy which doesn't change things too much). But I wasn't sure how to write it "formally"; could someone explain exactly what it means to be a "small" isotopy?

Comment: I suspect it means that you can choose an isotopy that is arbitrarily small (since the space of functions have a metric this makes sense).

Comment: @ConnorMalin ah yes, I forgot that there was an actual metric! Thanks!